# Why does a null string passed when expecting an array returns size of that array as 1?

Tags: java

I am extremely confused on multiple fronts. Can someone shed some light onto this. Here is a sample code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = null;
    abc(str);
}
static void abc(String... str){
    System.out.println(str.length);
}
```

> OUTPUT : 1

Comment: Dusting compile time the method call gets translated into `new String[]{null}` I am assuming.

Comment: @TA The aim here is to pass a null reference to a method call expecting an Array.

Comment: @SagarSaxena if you want to pass a null reference do not use variable arguments. (As a side note, if possible avoid passing null values, its better to pass an empty array... you just risk null pointer exceptions if you forget to do a `null` check somewhere inside)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's break it down. I renamed the parameter name to make it clearer.

```
static void abc(String... arrayOfStrings){
    System.out.println(arrayOfStrings.length);
}
```

The `String ...` is saying that instead of passing an array, you can pass the items one after the other as arguments and underneath they will be combined into an array for you. You can still pass an explicit object of type `String[]` (in which case it will not create the array for you), but passing just `null` assumes it is of type `String` not `String[]`.

You are doing `abc(null)` (because the argument you are passing is `null`).

So `arrayOfStrings` will have one item, which happens to be a  `null` reference.

So, `arrayOfStrings.length` returns `1`.

If you did `abc(null, null)`, you would get `2`.

If you did `abc((String[]) null)` you would get a `NullPointerException` because you would be trying to get the `length` of a `null` object reference. If you expect to pass nulls, make sure `abc()` checks for `null` before accessing the array passed as an argument.

As a general best practice avoid passing `null` as much as possible, it is better to pass an empty array. Passing `null` is just a poison pill, waiting for some method to forget to check for `null` and throwing `NullPointerException`.

Comment: That explains it. Thanks.

Comment: Sidenote: using `abc((String[]) null)` will throw an exception. Because then no additional array will be created

Comment: @Lino True, added an explanation for when an object explicitly typed `String[]` is passed.

Comment: "So arrayOfStrings will have one object, of type String which happens to be a  null reference" null can't be of String type and array of string does not contain any objects.

Comment: Fixed the wording. However null is contravariant with all Object types, including String.